# Error binding DataAdapter->DataSet->LINQ->ASP.Net DataGrid

Tags: asp.net, linq, data-binding, datagrid

I have the following code:

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(Connection.Instance.ConnectionString))
{
    // Open the connection
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        try
        {
            cmd.Connection = cn;

            cmd.CommandText = "Select Customers.CustomerID, Addresses.AddressCode, Addresses.FirstName, Addresses.LastName, Addresses.Address1, Addresses.City, Addresses.State, " +
            "Addresses.Zip, Addresses.Home AS HomePhone, Addresses.Phone AS WorkPhone, Addresses.EmailAddress  From Customers " +
            "LEFT OUTER JOIN Addresses ON Addresses.ID=Customers.AddressID " +
            "Where CustomerType IN ('HomeOwner', 'Home Owner') AND Customers.ResellerID=@ResellerID ";

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResellerID", base.UserID);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet dsCustomer = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(dsCustomer);

            var customers = from c in dsCustomer.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().AsQueryable()
                            where c.Field<string>("CustomerID") == txtSearchCriteria.Text
                            select c;

            dgCustomers.CurrentPageIndex = 0;

            dgCustomers.DataSource = customers;
            dgCustomers.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message + e.StackTrace);
        }
        finally
        {
            if ((cn != null) && (cn.State != ConnectionState.Closed))
                cn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Which is giving me the error

```
AllowCustomPaging must be true and VirtualItemCount must be set for a DataGrid with ID 'dgCustomers' when AllowPaging is set to true and the selected data source does not implement ICollection.   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid.CreateControlHierarchy(Boolean useDataSource)
```

How do I convert this LINQ query so that it can be pagable?

Note: This is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do.  I know in this example I could simply modify the SQL statement to include "And CustomerID=@CustomerID" and bypass LINQ completely.  But, in the bigger picture, I can't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is clear, you need to implement your paging logic to take advantage from paging. BTW, to make your code to work just use a ICollection as DataSource, changing this line:

```
dgCustomers.DataSource = customers.ToList();
```